# Is it possible to make an unwipable software?

Tags: android, operating-system, bios

So, I have being thinking a software that can outlive a total OS wipe. Is it possible to create a software of this nature?

Answer (score 0):

If you had software installed on a ROM (Read Only Memory) then it cannot be deleted save hardware failure of some sort. And assuming the reinstalled OS was configured to read it properly it would work perfectly fine, that is what the purpose of the BIOS is for. Although, there are ROM chips that are erasable (EEPROM) and modern BIOS chips nowadays are flashable for convenience purposes.